# Update Java code signing cert post deployment

Tags: java, ssl, signed

I have an app, used via Java Web Start, that was hit by the newest update (7u51) w.r.t not accepting self-signed certificates.  This app is sold and deployed to users (ie, not accessed via a webserver that I control).

I've purchased a new certificate from Verisign (Symantec, now), and was wondering if it's possible to simply send the users the new cert to sign the relevant files/import the cert, or do I have to recreate the JAR files with the signed certificate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you build your application or how you protect the private part of the certificate - usually, there is a passphrase involved. Are you really suggesting to spread these important details to other people?

You do realize that they can start signing *anything* using your key if you do, right?

Don't. Just ... don't.

Comment: I figured this was the case...I'm curious if we can sign only the pertinent JARs and redistribute them, or if the entire package should be re-signed.  Doing a reinstall of the application is a showstopper for most, although not being able to access it is one as well :)

Comment: Security is never free. My guess is that for Web Start, there will be signed list of the JARs which make up the application to prevent an attacker to replace them. So I think you will have to build a new WAR and deploy it.